# boost Shared_pointer NULL

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I'm using `reset()` as a default value for my shared_pointer (equivalent to a `NULL`).

But how do I check if the shared_pointer is `NULL`?

Will this return the right value ?

```
boost::shared_ptr<Blah> blah;
blah.reset()
if (blah == NULL) 
{
    //Does this check if the object was reset() ?
}
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use:

```
if (!blah)
{
    //This checks if the object was reset() or never initialized
}
```

Answer (score 11):

`if blah == NULL` will work fine. Some people would prefer it over testing as a bool (`if !blah`) because it's more explicit. Others prefer the latter because it's shorter.

Answer (score 9):

You can just test the pointer as a boolean:  it will evaluate to `true` if it is non-null and `false` if it is null:

```
if (!blah)
```

`boost::shared_ptr` and `std::tr1::shared_ptr` both implement the safe-bool idiom and C++0x's `std::shared_ptr` implements an explicit `bool` conversion operator.  These allow a `shared_ptr` be used as a boolean in certain circumstances, similar to how ordinary pointers can be used as a boolean.

Answer (score 8):

As shown in `boost::shared_ptr<>`'s [documentation](http://www.boost.org/libs/smart_ptr/#shared_ptr_conversions), there exists a boolean conversion operator:

```
explicit operator bool() const noexcept;
// or pre-C++11:
operator unspecified-bool-type() const; // never throws
```

So simply use the `shared_ptr<>` as though it were a `bool`:

```
if (!blah) {
    // this has the semantics you want
}
```